# Create a common header for Axios API call in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to make a common header which I can use in all of my API calls but I am facing some issues. I am calling APIs using Axios like this:

```
function signUp(data: object): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  return axios
    .post(`${baseUrl}/${v3}/signup`, data, {
      headers: authHeader(),
    })
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

Here is my authHeader function:

```
export function authHeader(): Header {
  const token: string | null = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const header: Header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  };
  if (token) {
    header.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return header;
}
```

My Header interface:

```
export interface Header extends AxiosHeaders {
  "Content-Type": string;
  Accept: string;
  Authorization?: string;
}
```

In my authHeader function, the header variable is giving an error, it says:

```
Type '{ "Content-Type": string; Accept: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Header': set, get, has, delete, and 23 more.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the headers this way:

```
const headers = new AxiosHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Accept: "application/json",
});
if (token) {
  headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
}
return headers;
```

Comment: Remember to click the ☑️ to mark your question as answered.